# NuGet Package Not working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-6, nuget-package

After updating Visual studio 2015, I am getting the following error when visual studio starts.
Nuget Operation failed
NuGet.Config is not a valid XML. 
*Path*

'.' hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, Position 1.

Also, i cannot use the package manager console anymore.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, but with no success. i am still getting the error above.

Any guidance on how to fix this would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 34):

Delete `NuGet.Config` from:

```
C:\Users\your-username\AppData\Roaming\NuGet
```

Upon re-opening VS2015 a new config file will be created and the issue should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue for me

Comment: For Windows users there is a shortcut, `win + R` and type `%appdata%`, and you will get into the page, or just copy and paste the path in the answer , haha

Answer (score 4):

Delete ".nuget" folder from C drive\users\username

> C:\Users\{username}\.nuget

and you can update or re-install the package.

This is work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any nuget.config file in your Solution?

The format have changed from fx:

```
<settings>
  <repositoryPath>..\..\packages</repositoryPath>
</settings>
```

To:

```
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\..\packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could also be a wrong xml version or that your nuget.config have BOM.

Answer (score 1):

Could be some of your packages have been cached?

Download the latest nuget.exe (from https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe) and open a command prompt (*preferably with administrator privileges*) and point to the location where you've download the nuget.exe and execute following commands (from command prompt or powershell console).

```
nuget.exe locals -clear global-packages
nuget.exe locals -clear http-cache
nuget.exe locals -clear temp
```

Then restart Visual Studio.